# Searching for a Particular Comic

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics

I am looking for a particular comic from the DC universe.

The basic premise is that four "super-villains" including Brainiac, a female wearing a superman symbol who can shape-shift (perhaps Matrix Supergirl), an ogre creature wearing a backwards superman symbol, and another female with psychic abilities kidnap Metron.  Orion and Lightray attempt a rescue but are captured by the villains.  Superman is left to form a team, rescue the hostages, and stop Brainiac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to tick a lot of boxes with the Superman crossover comic serial "[Panic in the Sky](http://www.comicvine.com/panic-in-the-sky/4045-55873/)"

> **Panic in the Sky**
>
> In the early 1990s, Brainiac returned in the "Panic in the Sky"
> storyline. He seized control of Warworld and manipulated Maxima into
> assisting him. Then he brainwashed Supergirl and the alien warrior
> Draaga before capturing Metron and setting off for Earth.
> Orion and Lightray of New Genesis attacked Warworld, but they were
> quickly taken down by Maxima and Supergirl. Brainiac sent the mental
> image of the New Gods captured to Superman in order to taunt him, and
> he also sent his "headship" (a green-hued variant of the pre-Crisis
> skull-like ship) to Earth in a punitive expedition.
>
> These acts prompted Superman to go on the offense rather than wait for
> the inevitable invasion. He gathered a coalition of most of the
> world's superheroes and launched a preemptive strike at Warworld
> before it could arrive on Earth.
>
> A small, elite force was left behind for any scouting forces that
> would be sent ahead. Superman led the attack on Warworld, where
> Supergirl and Draaga managed to shrug off their brainwashing and rally
> to Superman (although Draaga was killed in the fighting).
>
> Brainiac briefly took control of some of Earth's heroes, but it was
> not enough to turn the tide. Maxima would shortly switch sides in the
> fighting too, perceiving Brainiac as the true villain at last. Flash,
> Maxima, and the Metal Men attacked him in his lair, where Maxima
> managed to lobotomize him (but was stopped short of killing him). His
> vegetative body was taken back to New Genesis for observation.

[image]